# WebResource.axd not found error on azure appservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, web-deployment, webresource.axd

When I migrated Asp.net webform (framework 4.7) website to azure I encountered 404 not found error for WebResource.axd files I have included the handler manually in web.config like the following

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AssemblyResourceLoader-Integrated-4.0" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" 
           preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I also tried to configure handlers in system.web as well but with no luck.

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add   path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```

It only works when I deploy the site locally on IIS. Has anybody encountered this before?,Should I make any specific configuration in azure for that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click your webapp in local and enter F4, in `Properties`,switched the `managed pipeline mode` from `classic` to `integrated`, that fix it.

Or you could add a handler at `web.config`:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" /> 
</handlers>
```

Refer to this [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/52c20847-7558-4507-9d55-2620a98fb0a1/webresourceaxd-and-scriptresourceaxd-404-error?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Comment: Thanks Joey, My webapp is already at integrated mode, I will add the mentioned handler but for 64bit system . somthing like this 
 <add name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
I will let you know if that soleves my problem